# C# WPF Xaml: Globally set all text in a view to one color, and all backgrounds to another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Is there a way (using data binding or simply xaml) to set the background of  all elements in a view to one color, and all text to another?

I know I can edit each element in the view one by one, but I I'd like to see if this is possible with settings at a global level. Kind of like how everything by default is set to black on white.

I guess what I'm asking is if there is a feature/setting of a WPF application that offers what I'm looking for, and/or what I should search to find an answer online.

My project isn't using anything but what visual studio offers when you create a WPF project, so I can't use a prism or mvvm light approach.

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

> Globally...or simply XAML...
>   if there is a feature/setting of a WPF application that offers what I'm looking for

In Application Resource add style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Control">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value ="Blue"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value ="Red"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value ="Blue"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value ="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Based on your target element you want to set background.

Comment: Also, to be clear for the user, it can be also be the page's resource or even a target control's resource, providing scope as needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *"the background of all elements in a view"* you should be more specific, If by 'element' you mean `UIElement` then there is no `Background` property in `UIElement`. If it means `Control` then not all `UIElements`derive from `Control` (e.g. TextBlock) and finally if it means every `UIElement` derived type defined in your view that have a `Background` property, then you should add different styles for each type without setting the `x:key` to the `YourView.Resources` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: TextBlock is not a Control Type.

Answer (score 0):

uses controls collection through which you can control all controls in WPF